# File not updated when python script executed using escapeshellcmd

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi, openpyxl

Details

- Raspian OS (raspberry pi)
- Python3.9
- openpyxl library
- Apache Server,

I'm trying to run a small python script from an html/php page using apache server on a raspberry pi. The objective of the script is to take form data from HTML and transfer the information to a spreadsheeting using the openpyxl python library. I can run the script successfully from terminal without issue. (populates the cells as designed)

```php
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /home/pi/python_code/'Datapaq Code'/Test_File2.py");
$output = shell_exec($command); 
echo $output;
```

Here's where I struggle.  The above code **works** with a script using basic print functions.  The path and format correctly execute the simple script.  However when I substitute my target code the spreadsheet does not update.  Again this final code sucessfully executes from terminal.  The python script is below.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#import os 
#import sys
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Loading parameters.xlsx
wb = load_workbook('/home/pi/python_code/Datapaq Code/parameters.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

#print('arguments in sys.argv', sys.argv)

#print(sys.argv[0])
ws['C3'] = ('Test Run') #Filename sys.argv[1]
#ws['C4'] = int(sys.argv[2]) #Measurement Interval
#ws['C5'] = sys.argv[3] #probe1
#ws['C6'] = sys.argv[4] #probe2
#ws['C7'] = sys.argv[5] #probe3
        
wb.save('/home/pi/python_code/Datapaq Code/parameters.xlsx')
```

The troubleshooting I've done so far suggests a read write issue.  I tried some test code that has only loads and saves the file via `openpyxl` with no inputs from the php page... simply a trigger to run the script.  Nothing.

So in short the php code works, the `openpyxl` code works but I can't seem to pair them together.

Permissions issue?  Formating issue?  Apache configuration issue?

Any suggestions anyone might have would be greatly appreciated.  Struggling with this for a few days now.    Thanks

Comment: A permission issue would likely result in Python raising an exception. Perhaps the file is saved in "some unexpected location"? Also, post *actual* text, not images of code.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting suggestion... corrected above.  I searched all files and did not find an unexpected copy of the spreadsheet anywhere on the pi.